# How to perform a full text search after populate in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a twitter like clone and I am trying to build the search system to perform a general text lookup against all the tweet data. Each tweet stores a reference to the author and therefore I have to call populate before I can use .find()

I tried this to no avail:

```
const searchTerm = req.query.query;

Tweet.find()
  .limit(10)
  .populate("author")
  .find( { $text: { $search: `${searchTerm}` } })
  .then(data => {
    res.json({ tweets: data });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Here is the `Tweet` model

```
const TweetSchema = new Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  comments: [Comment.schema],
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user", required: true },
  replies: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

TweetSchema.index({ "$**": "text" });

module.exports = Tweet = mongoose.model("tweet", TweetSchema);
```